# Como separar números em python?

Tags: python

Escreva um algoritmo que recebe um valor inteiro m. Logo após, seu programa receberá uma sequência de valores inteiros maiores ou iguais a 0 e menores do que m, separados por vírgula.  Seu programa deve imprimir na tela quantas vezes cada número da sequência apareceu, em ordem.

Utilize o exemplo abaixo para entender como os dados serão recebidos e como a saída deve ser exibida.

Exemplo de entrada:

4
3,1,3,0,1,1,1,3,1,3

Exemplo de saída:

0,1
1,5
3,4

No exemplo acima, as entradas m = 4 e 3,1,3,0,1,1,1,3,1,3 representa uma sequência de números inteiros separados por vírgula. Já a saída indica que o número 0 apareceu 1 vez, o número 1 apareceu 5 vezes e o número 3 apareceu 4 vezes na sequência.

Apenas as seguintes funções são permitidas nesse exercício: input print int str split len append

Comment: Basicamente, é só adaptar as soluções dos links indicados acima no box azul. O primeiro diz como separar os números (basta trocar o `split(" ")` para `split(",")`) e o segundo explica como usar o `Counter`, que faz a contagem que vc precisa

Comment: Vc tentou ao menos ler os links indicados e adaptar o código que tem lá para o seu caso? **Se já tentou, basta [edit] a pergunta** colocando o código que fez e qual a dificuldade específica encontrada.